# ROR application continuous deployment from github/gitlab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, gitlab, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I Have developed a simple application in Ruby on Rails(ROR), pushed it on github and gitlab and deployed it on Ubuntu server provided by Digital Ocean. How can I achieve the continuous deployment such that whenever I pushed the changes on gitlab/github, it should make changes on VPS(virtual private server) i.e. Ubuntu server? I used `capistrano3` fro deployment.

Comment: Are you using both GitLab and GitHub. On GitLab you'd use the runners they provide

Comment: Yes, using both. Just for the leaning. Thanks for the reply. Will have a look on runners.

Comment: I'm working on an answer to your question with possible steps or guide. Let me know if you need any further clarifications after you've gone thru

Comment: Have you tried it now? If you're OK with the answer please mark as accepted so it can help other users with similar problem

Answer (score 1):

For `GitLab`

create a file `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the root of your rails app.

Since you're using `Capistrano`, you want to be sure that ruby is pre-installed

Add `image: ruby:2.3` to the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

Next we need to install `Capistrano` when we're deploying

Add these to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_application:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - gem install capistrano
```

However it gets dicey because `Capistrano` requires ssh to deploy to your server. It's advisable that you use an ssh-agent. Hence we'll modify the `.gitlab-ci.yml` again to look like this

```
image: ruby:2.3 #your_ruby_version
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_application:
  stage: deploy
  script:
   - which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - ssh-add <(echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - gem install capistrano
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do I still need to register a runner when using `.gitlab-cli/yml` ?

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't respond you earlier. Actually, I havn't tried it yet, as I don't have the admin privileges of Gitlab repository. I will mark it as soon as i get it works. Thanks